How to select a float value from a dataframe column which is in dictionary form in python?
I have a dataframe like this:
Date                      comp
01-01-2022      {'dfp':25.02,'ftp':12.06}
01-02-2022      {'dfp':12.01,'ftp':40.05}
01-03-2022      {'dfp':50.20,'ftp':35.25}

I am trying to create a new column which has only the dfp value from the comp column.
Expected Output:
Date                      comp                   New
01-01-2022      {'dfp':25.02,'ftp':12.06}       25.02
01-02-2022      {'dfp':12.01,'ftp':40.05}       12.01
01-03-2022      {'dfp':50.20,'ftp':35.25}       50.20

I tried the below code to execute the same:
def new_col(x):
   for i in range(len(df)):
       return x[i]['dfp']

df['New'] = df['comp'].apply(new_col)

But the above code creates error. where am i going wrong?

Apply applies to each sub-element, not to the series or its values. If you substitute lambda d: d['dfp'] for new_col it should work

You can use the .str accessor also.

My %timeit for apply(lambda d: d[key]) vs str[key] gives 3.08 s vs 4.15 s respectively; this almost certainly because str operations aren't "truly" vectorised

Use can use the .str accessor to get data from dictionary in pandas dataframes:
df['New'] = df['comp'].str['dfp']

Output:
         Date                          comp    New
0  01-01-2022  {'dfp': 25.02, 'ftp': 12.06}  25.02
1  01-02-2022  {'dfp': 12.01, 'ftp': 40.04}  12.01
2  01-03-2022   {'dfp': 50.2, 'ftp': 35.25}  50.20

Handles missing keys very nicely without extra code checking for NaN.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['01-01-2022', '01-02-2022', '01-03-2022', '01-04-2022'],
                   'comp':[{'dfp':25.02, 'ftp':12.06},{'dfp':12.01, 'ftp':40.04},{'dfp':50.20, 'ftp':35.25},
                          {'ftps':100}]})


df['New'] = df['comp'].str['dfp']

Output:
         Date                          comp    New
0  01-01-2022  {'dfp': 25.02, 'ftp': 12.06}  25.02
1  01-02-2022  {'dfp': 12.01, 'ftp': 40.04}  12.01
2  01-03-2022   {'dfp': 50.2, 'ftp': 35.25}  50.20
3  01-04-2022                 {'ftps': 100}    NaN


I construct a test data frame like so.
df = pd.Series([{'a': 123}] * 10_000_000, name='d').to_frame()
s = df['d']

There are three methods to do this. You can apply an unwrap, s.apply(lambda d: d['a']); use the string accessor to slice s.str['a']; or use a list comprehension, [i['a'] for i in s.values].
Based on my testing with IPython, the fastest method is the third.
%timeit df['i'] = s.apply(lambda d: d['a'])
3.13 s ± 292 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df['i'] = s.str['a']
4.2 s ± 420 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df['i'] = [i['a'] for i in s.values]
2.76 s ± 226 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


If there are missing keys, yes, you'll get KeyError. Including a ternary to check for missing keys with the list comprehension is still more performant than s.str['a'] (which handles that automatically).
%timeit df['i'] = [i['a'] if 'a' in i.keys() else np.nan for i in s.values]
3.7 s ± 294 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


Hilariously, converting the data to Polars (import polars as pl), unnesting, and then converting it back to Pandas is still more performant. (At least, for this single-key-dictionary toy example.)
%timeit pl.from_pandas(df).unnest('d').to_pandas()
1.84 s ± 217 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


How do you hand nulls or missing keys such as: df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['01-01-2022', '01-02-2022', '01-03-2022', '01-04-2022'],                    'comp':[{'dfp':25.02, 'ftp':12.06},{'dfp':12.01, 'ftp':40.04},{'dfp':50.20, 'ftp':35.25},                           {'ftps':100}]})
